# PHP - Get specific key and its value in an array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I get a specific `key` in an `array`. For me to get its value.

Sample code output in a `print_r`.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => Thu, 2 Mar 2017 10:41:22 [ANI] => 6616706413 [ANI STATE] => CA [DISPOSITION] => 290 - SCHEDULED [NOTES] => received a letter from us His wife called in to make the appointment. I scheduled him for May 2nd at 10:45am in Sherman Oaks, provided address and number to call for directions. Thank you! [CALL ID] => 856217 [DNIS] => 8882900004 [CALL SURVEY RESULT] => [CUSTOMER NAME] => Louie Lopez [RECORDINGS] => [TALK TIME] => 00:06:30 [AFTER CALL WORK TIME] => 00:02:07 [number1] => 6616706413 [first_name] => Louie [last_name] => Lopez [1. How did you hear about us?] => [WORKSHEET ID] => ) 

[1] => Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => Thu, 2 Mar 2017 11:02:37 [ANI] => 9517227626 [ANI STATE] => CA [DISPOSITION] => 290 - WAITLIST [NOTES] => Calling to schedule via a flyer he rec'd. His information auto populated so I took a message to confirm with you before scheduling. You can reach him at 9517227626 [CALL ID] => 856311 [DNIS] => 8882900004 [CALL SURVEY RESULT] => [CUSTOMER NAME] => Donald Elvert Scott [RECORDINGS] => [TALK TIME] => 00:01:35 [AFTER CALL WORK TIME] => 00:00:29 [number1] => 9519407401 [first_name] => Donald Elvert [last_name] => Scott [1. How did you hear about us?] => [WORKSHEET ID] => )
```

I want to get the `TIMESTAMP` `key` on the above code.

Comment: `$Array['Middlename']`...?

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-61) before you ask something here!